# Cannot acces evnironment variable in Ant file(build.xml)

Tags: ant

I had written an ant file. I want to access TOMCAT_HOME environmental variable.I tried in the following way:

```
<property environment="env"/>
    <property name="TOMCAT" value="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}"/>
<echo>${TOMCAT}</echo>
```

OUTPUT:
    ${env.TOMCAT_HOME}

Output should be the environmental variable TOMCAT_HOME value

Note : i am using Redhat Linux

Comment: Does echoing ${env.TOMCAT_HOME} in your linux host prints required value?. And are you sourcing any profile or running any sript prior to your ant task to set it?

Comment: no it is printing as $(env.TOMCAT_HOME) and i am not running any script to set it, as it is already exported.

Comment: on your linux machine you want to echo $TOMCAT_HOME, not ${env.TOMCAT_HOME}